# SwipeRefreshLayout: Scrolling in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

I have a problem. If I want to scroll up the ListView the SwipeRefreshLayout will be triggered.

[Here is the example of the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VURT.png)

The text is german so....
Beneath "Ausstehende Order:" and "Letzte Order:" is a ListView. I can't scroll in this ListView because of the SwipeRefreshLayout.
I tried a fix. It tests if the ListView is scrolled up then the SwipeRefreshLayout will be enabled. But this fix is not appropriate for this specific problem.

**EDIT: The ListView does not fill the whole screen just a small part !**

**EDIT 2:**

```
<ConstraintLayout>
    <Other TextView> </Other TextView>
    <ListView> </ListView>  
</ConstraintLayout>
```

That is the code for the fragment

Here the basic activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout    >

<FrameLayout>      
</FrameLayout>

<RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/layout_top_tabs"/>

    </RelativeLayout>     

    <RelativeLayout>          

        <FrameLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <FrameLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- bottom navigation -->
    <include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_navigation_view"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If left out the unnecessary code

Thanks for all replies.

Comment: By the sounds of it your SwipeRefreshLayout takes up the whole width/height of the parent layout?

Comment: No the ListView is just a small part it does not fill the hole screen

Comment: Posting the XML of the layout — or at least the structural parts of it — may be helpful.

Comment: @KT_ edited the question